# Google Play Console App Analytics extremely lackluster?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I am trying to find stats about App Referers and Web Referers for my Android App. I have these stats in itunes for the iOS version, but cannot find them anywhere in the Google Play Developer Console. Do they exist?

I can then see how many downloads were made from users coming from Facebook, Instagram, etc ...

Second thing, the exports: is there a way to export data in one block (example: a year) instead of monthly reports? I have to combine 12 different reports for each stat to make a yearly report, and than do that for every stat I need. It is a waste of time.

I'd love your insights, as I have been very disappointed with the Google Play Developer Console compared to itunes.

Answer (score 0):

This information is in the [Acquisition and conversion funnel report](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6263332)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I had found that, but I export the data the files are empty. They only have column headers, even though on the Google Console some data is shown.